# implementation Strcat Function

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, function

I've got a programming question about the implementation of `strcat()` function.
I have been trying to solve that problem and I got some Access violation error.

My created function:

```
char str_cat(char str1, char str2)
{
    return str1-'\0'+str2;
}
```

what is wrong in the above code?

One more question please,
is "iostream" a header file? where can I get it?

thanks

Comment: Please choose one of `C` or `C++`. In `C` the answer will involve pointers, in `C++`, I think, it will involve `std::string`.

Comment: and people are still throwing answers (code) at him!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is right in the above code.

- You need to take `char *` parameters
- You need to return a `char *` if you have to return something (which isn't needed)
- You'll need to loop over the string copying individual characters - no easy solution with `+` and `-`
- You'll need to 0-terminate the result

E.g. like this:

```
void strcat(char * Dest, char const * Src) {
  char * d = Dest;
  while (*d++);
  char const * s = Src;
  while (*s) { *d++ = *s++; }
  *d = 0;
}
```

*Why* do you need to do this? There's a perfectly good `strcat` in the standard library, and there's a perfectly good `std::string` which you can use `+` on.

Comment: this is obviously homework, why are you so intent on doing it for him?

Comment: @Ernest: Given the level of his question he will not be able to explain the while loops - and will have to reimplement it in order for his teacher not to catch him at copying.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, *everything* is wrong with this function, even the return type and argument types. It should look like

```
char * strcat(const char *str1, const char *str2)
```

and it should work by allocating a new block of memory large enough to hold the concatenated strings using either malloc (for C) or new (for C++), then copy both strings into it. I think you've got your (home)work cut out for you, though, as I don't think you know much of what any of that means.

Answer (score 1):

Don't want to sound negative but there is not much right with this code.

Firstly, strings in C are char*, not char.

Second, there is no way to 'add' or 'subtract' them the way you would hope (which is sort of kind of possible in, say, python).

iostream is the standard I/O header for C++, it should be bundled with your distribution.

I would **really** suggest a tutorial on pointers to get you going - [this](http://home.earthlink.net/~momotuk/pointers.pdf) I found just by googling "ansi c pointers" - I'm guessing the problem asks you for a C answer as opposed to C++, since in C++ you would use std::string and the overloaded operator+.